# Compare large .txt file against array of values

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io

Good day, I am trying to compare a fairly large text file, about 100k lines against an array of between 1000 and 14000 values. The purpose of this is that a user has a text file of values, 1 per line, and the array contains pieces of information that may or may not match each line. Each line in the text file is unique and each item in the array is unique.

Eg text file structure :[image: 1]: [![https://imgur.com/a/xOwYoal]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqJov.png)

The array (outfitCell) will contain the first word of each line but may contain all or none of some matches within the text file, eg it will contain the word  "Is" but wont contain the rest of the line. I need it to retain the whole line and write it to a new file in a new path.

I have tried to use file stream and the standard stream reader and writer, but it takes about 50 seconds to do the comparison and write out the lines that "start with" the items from the array into a new txt file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could make this faster, I have had a look online but cant seem to find anything useful.

```
public static void CopyActiveFiles(List<string> files, string targetLocation, OutfitCell[] activeCells)
        {
            string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "tempPermit.txt");
            try
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                            {
                                using (var writer = File.CreateText(tempFile))
                                {
                                    string line;
                                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
                                            foreach (var activeCell in activeCells)
                                            {
                                                if (line.StartsWith(activeCell.Name))
                                                {

                                                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                                                }
                                            }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    File.SetAttributes(tempFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Copy(tempFile, Path.Combine(targetLocation, Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

Comment: Linq has some good options for comparing 2 sets of collections. Generally if you have large files, you stream small chunks at a time and then compare that to what you have in memory(the array). Another way is to split the work out into different threads with the `TaskFactory` and maybe compare say 4 items from the file at one time asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go.

Comment: Use a lookup from `ToLookup` to group the `activeCells` `Name` values into smaller batches, lookup e.g. the first two characters of each line in the lookup and then test against the smaller batch. Knowledge of distribution of the `Name` values would help decide how to group. In your code, creating a `List<string>` from the values once and using a `for` loop to test against them would be faster than `foreach` and property references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break things out into 2-3 functions. The calling function, the file function, and the thread work function.

```
    public static void CopyActiveFiles(List<string> files, string targetLocation, OutfitCell[] activeCells)
    {
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            CheckFile(file, activeCells);
        }
    }

    private static void CheckFile(string file, OutfitCell[] activeCells)
    {
        // Thread call
        // declare some thread safe collection.
        // var lines = File.ReadLines(file).Skip(<index>).Take(<count>);
        // Use a variant of the above line to grab a section of lines from the file to then ship out to threads.
    }
```

https://www.nimaara.com/counting-lines-of-a-text-file/

That link will help you count the lines in the file. This is useful for dividing up the file into chunks. Math will be required. Probably loop through x number of times with y items to count and the last block will be of size z.

Comment: This helped a lot, down to 12 seconds per file which is within my margin.

Answer (score 1):

I created a large file (133k lines) from the cmudict words file, using just the words over two characters long and adding 70 random ASCII characters to the end of each line. I also stored the words in another file and pulled between 1000 and 14,000 of them into a `List<string>` named `values`.

Using `ToLookup`, I grouped the `values` by the first two characters and just compared lines against the appropriate sub-group. I also took out the `BufferedStream` as various blogs showed that it doesn't improve performance for reading, and in this case slowed it down.

Running your code against my data took around 14.7 seconds to create a result file. Running the lookup code took around 0.2 seconds. Indexing with 3 characters cut that in half to 0.1 seconds for an over 150 times speedup. Constraining the `values` size to be over 10,000 took the time to 137 seconds down to 0.267 seconds for an over 500 times speedup (with 3 character indexes).

You can create `values` from `activeCells` with

```
var values = activeCells.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

Then use this code:

```
var possibles = values.ToLookup(v => v.Substring(0, 2));
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(tempFile)) {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                var index = line.Substring(0, 2);
                foreach (var value in possibles[index]) {
                    if (line.StartsWith(value)) {
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indexing the first few characters is not the best way to go about this. I suspect there are names as part of lines and with lots of duplicates, that will cause performance issues and bad data.

Comment: @DavidBentley Lots of duplicates is fine - reducing 100,000 comparisons by 2x or 3x would still be a significant improvement, and given that the array contains only unique elements, and that there are up to 14,000 values in it, I doubt if the duplicates are nearly that many. You did make me think about improving the `StartsWith` to skip the first few characters since we already know they match, but that would require `Span` to prevent extra allocation erasing the improvement.